# Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads. broke my project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads. v10.2.1 My project broke, and this message appears

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0012  The type 'FragmentActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71f3e3261ac778b5'. App16   C:\Users\jon\Documents\New folder\App16 - Copy (8)\App16\MainActivity.cs    11  Active

How to fix this?

Target Framwork 8.0,

Minimum 4.4,

Target Android Vesion 8.0
[image: Print]

[image: Print 2]

> I found the problem, it was conflict between the CrossLight RecyclerView package with V4. I unplugged CrossLight and reinstalled the V7 package. Everything is OK

Comment: What version of `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads` did you install?

Comment: @SushiHangover 10.2.1

Comment: 42.1021.1 yes @SushiHangover

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Android Support Libraries. Your Xamarin version must also be updated. Try it. Let me know if it works.

Lastly, put your projects as close to your C drive as possible.

Comment: Your VS2017 IDE needs to be updated too. Click on the yellow icon above. There's a ton of factors why you're getting that error.